# length() in R to determine the number of observations in a dataframe

Tags: r

I try to use the length() to determine the number of observations in a dataframe. If I use length(data), it will give me the number of the columns; If I use length(data$var1), it will give me the number of elements in the var1. How do I use the length() to determine total observations (# of columns * # of element in a column).

Thank you

Comment: With `data.frame`, `length` implies the number of columns because a `data.frame` is a `list` with elements having equal number of observations with some attributes..  So, it is similar to `length` of a `list` i.e. the number of elements or columns.  Using `length` can have different output depending on the class.  A `matrix` returns the total number of elements i.e number of rows* number of columns `length(matrix(1:25, 5, 5))`

Comment: Thank you. I try to explore the possibility of length() based on the requirement. So is length() by itself not enough to determine the observations of a dataframe?

Comment: @QianruSong if you need total number of observations with `length` only do `length(as.matrix(data))` or `length(t(data))`

Comment: Both work for me, thank you

Comment: You can do `length(data) * length(data$var1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to use only `length`, then convert to `matrix` and apply the `length`.  It will return the total number of observations

```
length(as.matrix(data))
```

Or conversion to `matrix` can be done by `t`ransposing

```
length(t(data))
```

---

`length` directly applying on a `data.frame` returns the number of elements or columns as a `data.frame` is a `list` with each element having the same `length` (along with some attributes)

Answer (score 5):

Use `nrow(df)` instead to get the number of rows and `ncol(df)` for columns. There's also `dim()`.

Comment: I am asked to use only length() to determine the observations of a dataframe, could I? Should I use length(data)*nrow(data)?

Comment: That's a strange requirement. Maybe `length(data) *length(data[,0])`? Do you call every cell an observation? I usually call just rows as observations, but I think that is different for each domain area.

Comment: As Daniel said, the simplest answer  is dim().

Answer (score 1):

`prod(dim(data))` or (probably more readable) `nrow(data) * nrow(data)` is preferred to  `length(as.matrix(data))` as the latter is going to be computationally expensive.

```r
DF <- data.frame(x = seq_len(1e8), y = seq_len(1e8))
 bench::mark(length(as.matrix(DF)), prod(dim(DF)))
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.
#> # A tibble: 2 x 10
#>   expression           min          mean        median        max `itr/sec`
#>   <chr>           <bch:tm>      <bch:tm>      <bch:tm>   <bch:tm>     <dbl>
#> 1 length(as~ 1789966.700us 1789966.700us 1789966.700us 1789.967ms   5.59e-1
#> 2 prod(dim(~       2.200us       3.097us       2.500us    2.174ms   3.23e+5
#> # ... with 4 more variables: mem_alloc <bch:byt>, n_gc <dbl>, n_itr <int>,
#> #   total_time <bch:tm>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: unfortunately this is not robust to handling vectors as well. Just a note to the unwary out there...